# FileBasedConfigurationBuilder from Apache Commons Configuration2 not writing the configuration file

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons-config

I need to write a simple configuration file using `apache-commons-configuration` but no matter what I try, it's not writing anything to the file.

This is how the file should look like

```
<config>
  <foo>bar</foo>
</config>
```

This is what I'm doing to write the foo configuration:

```
private static final String USER_CONFIGURATION_FILE_NAME = "config.xml";

private final Path configFilePath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".myapp",
USER_CONFIGURATION_FILE_NAME);

private final FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<XMLConfiguration> configBuilder=
  new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<>(XMLConfiguration.class)
      .configure(new Parameters().xml().setFile(configFilePath.toFile()));

/**
 * Sets the foo configuration to the given {@link String}
 * 
 * @param foo The configuration to be set up
 * @throws ConfigurationException If any error occur while setting the property on the
 *         configuration file
 */
public void setfoo(final String bar) throws ConfigurationException {
  checkNotNull(bar);
  final Configuration config = configBuilder.getConfiguration();

  config.setProperty("foo", bar);

  configBuilder.save();
}

/**
 * Retrieves the foo set up on the configuration file
 * 
 * @return The foo set up on the configuration file
 * @throws ConfigurationException If any error occur while setting the property on the
 *         configuration file
 * @throws NoSuchElementException If there is no foo set up
 */
public String getFoo() throws ConfigurationException {
  return configBuilder.getConfiguration().getString("foo");
}
```

Am I missing something? In [Apache Commons Configuration - File-based Configurations](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_filebased.html#File-based_Configurations) I can't see any other information needed to set up the file, so I really don't know what I'm missing here.

---

For some reason the `FileBasedConfiguration` is not setting up the xml file by itself, so I had to create it manually and set up the root element, like this:

```
configFilePath.toFile().createNewFile();

final Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(configFilePath);
writer.write("<config></config>");  //sets the root element of the configuration file
writer.flush();
```

Shouldn't `FileBasedConfiguration` take care of this for me, or this is a step that's not documented on `apache-commons`?

Comment: I'm trying to find the answer to this one too

Comment: I'm trying the same but for a simple properties file. Followed same steps from documentation but when I check application.properties file, it hasn't updated my changes.

Comment: @Clawdidr, that looks like a flush problem, are you making sure you're calling the save method from the builder?

Comment: @martinatime yeeah, it's a pity I couldn't find an answer to this problem at the time... If anyone find out if there's a way of creating the file automatically, I'll gladly accept the answer. Thank you! :)

Comment: @MagnoNascimento, I was able to solve the issue. Problem was where I was placing my properties file. It's now in WEB-INF/classes/application.properties and is being updated. My issue now is that changes are not being picked up by PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer :/